# Toggle Service Activity

Tags: android, service

I'm developing a service that need to run foreground, and users can toggle it on/off through an activity. So basically, the activity MAY be killed, but the service is safe as long as it is not stopped by user.

However, I'm getting this trouble: how to turn off the service if it is on? That mean, if my activity was killed, then restarted, so I get no reference of the started service intent to call `stopService`.

Below is my current code. It works fine if the user call deactivate after the service is started by the same activity. The button status is always correct, but when my activity is restarted by the OS, `this.serviceIntent` is null.

```
protected boolean isServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (SynchronizationService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    this.togglingByCode = true;
    this.butActivate.setChecked(this.isServiceRunning());
    this.togglingByCode = false;
}

public void onActivateButtonClick(final boolean pIsChecked) {
    if (this.togglingByCode) { return; }

    if (pIsChecked) {
        this.saveSettings();

        this.serviceIntent = new Intent(this, SynchronizationService.class);
        this.serviceIntent.putExtra(KEY_WEBSERVICE, this.txtWebService.getText().toString());
        this.serviceIntent.putExtra(KEY_PASSWORD, this.txtPassword.getText().toString());
        this.serviceIntent.putExtra(KEY_INTERVAL, Integer.parseInt(this.txtRefreshInterval.getText().toString()));
        this.serviceIntent.putExtra(KEY_TIMEOUT, this.preferences.getInt(KEY_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT));
        this.serviceIntent.putExtra(KEY_RETRY, this.preferences.getInt(KEY_RETRY, DEFAULT_RETRY));

        this.startService(this.serviceIntent);
    } else {
        this.stopService(this.serviceIntent);
        this.serviceIntent = null;
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to stop the service correctly. Thank you.

P.s: I know a trick that make `serviceIntent` `static`, but I don't feel safe about it. If there is no any other way, then I will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply initialize your serviceIntent in the activity's onCreate... You can start your service, kill your activity, reopen it and stop the service with the same serviceIntent.

Comment: Very nice :) Thank you very much.